# My controller method release_reservation is not saving the attributes with new values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a rails newbie. I'm sure my question probably be answered with a line or two. I just cant figure out whats wrong. Please help! Thank you for your time in advance.
So here's my problem :
My controller method `release_reservation` is not able to save the attributes with new values in the database. With my limited rails knowledge I'm suspecting it has something to with `routes.rb` but I am not able to narrow down to the actual issue.
Here's `release_reservation` which is defined in `reservations_controller.rb`

```
def release_reservation
@reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
@reservation.reserve_from = DateTime.now
@reservation.reserve_to = DateTime.now
@reservation.reserve_status = false

respond_to do |format|
if  @reservation.update_attributes(params[:reservation]) 
  format.html {redirect_to release_reservation_reservation,  :notice => 'Machine was    successfully released' }# show.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @reservation }
else
  format.html { render :action => "show" }
  format.json { render :json => @reservation.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
end
end
end
```

Here's the model `Reservation.rb`

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :machine_reserver,  :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 50 }

validates :machine_name, :uniqueness => {:scope => :machine_platform}

validate :check_reservation_end_date, :on => :update 
validate :check_reservation_from_date

default_scope :order => 'updated_at DESC'

def date_reset
self.reserve_from = DateTime.now
self.reserve_to = DateTime.now
end 

def check_reservation_end_date
   if self.reserve_to < self.reserve_from 
     errors.add(:reserve_to, "cannot be lesser than or equal to start date")
   end 
end

def check_reservation_from_date
if self.reserve_from < DateTime.now
  errors.add(:reserve_from, "cannot be lesser than current date & time")
end
end
end
```

Here's View file from where I want to call `release_reservation`

```
<h1>Reservation</h1>
<br>    
<p>
<% if @reservation.reserve_to > DateTime.now %>
This machine will be released in 
<% duration = @reservation.reserve_to - DateTime.now %> 
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(duration) %>
<% end %>
</p>   
<p>
  <b>Machine name: </b>
  <%= @reservation.machine_name %>
</p>    
<p>
  <b>Machine platform: </b>
  <%= @reservation.machine_platform %>
</p>    
<p>
<% if  @reservation.reserve_to > DateTime.now %>
  <b>Reserved by: </b>
  <%= @reservation.machine_reserver %>
<% end %>
</p>    
<p>
<% if  @reservation.reserve_to > DateTime.now %>
  <b>Reserve from: </b>
  <%= @reservation.reserve_from.to_formatted_s(:long)  %>
<% end %>
</p>    
<p>
<% if  @reservation.reserve_to > DateTime.now %>
  <b>Reserve to: </b>
  <%= @reservation.reserve_to.to_formatted_s(:long)  %>
<% end %>
</p>    
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= link_to 'Back', reservations_path, :class => 'btn'  %>
<% if  @reservation.reserve_to > DateTime.now %>
<%= link_to 'Release', {:controller => 'reservations', :action => 'release_reservation', :id => @reservation}, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :class => 'btn btn-danger' %> 
<% else %>
<%= link_to 'Reserve', edit_reservation_path(@reservation), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %> 
<% end %>
```

Here's `routes.rb`

```
Reserver::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :reservations do
    member do
    get 'release_reservation'
       end
 end
  resources :machines  
  resources :reserves
  resources :platforms
  resources :users
  root :to => 'reservations#index'  
end
```

rake routes

```
release_reservation_reservation GET    /reservations/:id/release_reservation(.:format) reservations#release_reservation
                   reservations GET    /reservations(.:format)                         reservations#index
                                POST   /reservations(.:format)                         reservations#create
                new_reservation GET    /reservations/new(.:format)                     reservations#new
               edit_reservation GET    /reservations/:id/edit(.:format)                reservations#edit
                    reservation GET    /reservations/:id(.:format)                     reservations#show
                                PUT    /reservations/:id(.:format)                     reservations#update
                                DELETE /reservations/:id(.:format)                     reservations#destroy
```

Comment: I tried setting 'put' for release_reservation in routes.rb but I get this error   
'No route matches [GET] "/reservations/4/release_reservation"'

Answer (score 0):

I think your validations prevent instance from persisting